# allowing to update gridview depending on user authentication asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a web app in asp.net running on windows authentication

i want only a specific user to be able to update, while the other users will only be able to view.

how do customize the gridview so that only a specific user has the option to update?

Comment: How are you doing the updates through the GridView. There are many ways to skin that cat.

Comment: @james i just enabled the update link thing

Comment: So you're using the built-in edit functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the GridView is bound, try adding this code somewhere:

```
CommandField editButton = GridView.Columns.OfType<CommandField>().ElementAtOrDefault(0);
if (editButton != null)
    editButton.Visible = HttpContext.Current.user.Identity.Name == "<USER NAME>";
```

Comment: looks like an awesome solution are there any other ones that you can think of?

Comment: i also wanted to ask you this: http://serverfault.com/questions/303184/configuring-asp-net-to-work-with-roles-in-windows-authentication

Comment: I think that's probably the easiest solution for your situation. Lookiong at your last comment, are you looking to limit editing to a certain role?

Comment: no it is unrelated, im just having a very difficult time adding users to a role. when i search for users it returns 0 each time

Comment: Did you add the roleManager key in the web.config for AD authentication? If not, you need to add the key: <roleManager enabled="true" 
            defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" />

Comment: i have it set up like this now: <roleManager enabled="true" /> and then i tried what you suggested and it gave me this error The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: The configured Role Provider (WindowsTokenRoleProvider) relies upon Windows authentication to determine the groups that the user is allowed to be a member of. ASP.NET Role Manager cannot be used to manage Windows users and groups.

Comment: Please use the SQLRoleProvider if you would like to support custom user/role assignment. at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.CallWebAdminHelperMethod(Boolean isMembership, String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes) at ASP.security_roles_manageallroles_aspx.BindGrid() at ASP.security_roles_manageallroles_aspx.Page_Load() at System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.ArglessFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o) at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()

Comment: So you want AD authentication and custom roles, or AD authentication and AD roles?

Comment: @JamesJohnson let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2678/discussion-between-i-and-james-johnson)

Comment: i did what you said with the command line and still same issue